# Rotating HDC using WinGDI

Tags: c++, gdi

This post is code dense so ignore the first block. It is only there as a reference to see how the function initially worked.

I'm currently trying to perform a -270 or 90 degree rotation on hdcText in the following code:

```
    void CImageWindow::Show()
        {
            BITMAP bm;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            //Start Drawing Segment
            int iWidth = m_rLocation.right - m_rLocation.left;
            int iHeight = m_rLocation.bottom - m_rLocation.top;

            //Drawing plane for this window
            HDC hdcScreen = BeginPaint(m_hWindow, &ps);
            HBITMAP hWorking = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, iWidth,iHeight);
            SelectObject(hdcScreen, hWorking);
            SetStretchBltMode(hdcScreen, HALFTONE);
            SetBrushOrgEx(hdcScreen,0,0,0);

            //Background
            HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
            HBITMAP hBmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(m_hInstance, m_sTexture.c_str(), IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
            SelectObject(hdcMem, hBmp);
            GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(bm), &bm);
            StretchBlt(hdcScreen,0,0, iWidth, iHeight, hdcMem, 0,0,bm.bmWidth,bm.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);

            //Text
            HDC hdcText = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
            HBITMAP hbmpText = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcText, iWidth,iHeight);
            SelectObject(hdcText, hbmpText);
            RECT rTextLoc;
            rTextLoc.top = iHeight/4;
            rTextLoc.bottom = 3 * iHeight / 4;
            rTextLoc.left = iWidth / 4;
            rTextLoc.right =3 * iWidth / 4;
            SetTextColor(hdcText, RGB(255,255,255));
            SetBkMode(hdcText, TRANSPARENT);
            HFONT hfFont = CreateFont((iHeight/2) - 2, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"Tahoma"); //-2 to ensure it can fit in the rectangle
            SelectObject(hdcText, hfFont);
            DrawText(hdcText, m_sIdentifier.c_str(), -1, &rTextLoc, DT_CENTER | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER);
            StretchBlt(hdcScreen, 0,0,iWidth,iHeight, hdcText, 0,0,iWidth,iHeight, SRCINVERT);

            if(m_bFlipped)
                StretchBlt(hdcScreen, iWidth,iHeight,-iWidth,-iHeight, hdcScreen, 0,0,iWidth,iHeight, SRCCOPY);

             DeleteObject(hWorking);
             DeleteObject(hBmp);
             DeleteObject(hbmpText);

             DeleteObject(hfFont);

             DeleteObject(hdcMem);
             DeleteObject(hdcText);

             EndPaint( m_hWindow, &ps );

        }
```

I've attempted to do the following to solve this issue.

1. Using XForm to rotate the HDC.

This is not having any effect on the position of hdcText. I'm unsure why and the information is sparse.

NOTE:I have played around with the XForm values so even if these are incorrect, I don't think this is the issue.

```
    void CImageWindow::Show()
        {
            BITMAP bm;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            //Start Drawing Segment
            int iWidth = m_rLocation.right - m_rLocation.left;
            int iHeight = m_rLocation.bottom - m_rLocation.top;

            //Drawing plane for this window
            HDC hdcScreen = BeginPaint(m_hWindow, &ps);
            HBITMAP hWorking = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, iWidth,iHeight);
            SelectObject(hdcScreen, hWorking);
            SetStretchBltMode(hdcScreen, HALFTONE);
            SetBrushOrgEx(hdcScreen,0,0,0);

            //Background
            HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
            HBITMAP hBmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(m_hInstance, m_sTexture.c_str(), IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
            SelectObject(hdcMem, hBmp);
            GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(bm), &bm);
            StretchBlt(hdcScreen,0,0, iWidth, iHeight, hdcMem, 0,0,bm.bmWidth,bm.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);

            //Text
            HDC hdcText = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
            //Added
            SetGraphicsMode(hdcText, GM_ADVANCED);
            SetMapMode(hdcText, MM_TEXT); 

            HBITMAP hbmpText = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcText, iWidth,iHeight);
            SelectObject(hdcText, hbmpText);

            RECT rTextLoc;
            rTextLoc.top = iHeight/4;
            rTextLoc.bottom = 3 * iHeight / 4;
            rTextLoc.left = iWidth / 4;
            rTextLoc.right =3 * iWidth / 4;
            SetTextColor(hdcText, RGB(255,255,255));
            SetBkMode(hdcText, TRANSPARENT);

            lf.lfWeight = FW_NORMAL;
            lstrcpy(lf.lfFaceName, _T("Tahoma"));
            float iAngle = 2700;
            //float fAngle = -static_cast<float>(iAngle) * static_cast<float>(M_PI) / 180.0f; 

            rTextLoc.top = iHeight/4;
            rTextLoc.bottom = 3 * iHeight / 4;
            rTextLoc.left = iWidth / 4;
            rTextLoc.right =3 * iWidth / 4;

            HFONT hFont = CreateFont((iHeight/2) - 2, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"Tahoma"); //-2 to ensure it can fit in the rectangle

            long y = (rTextLoc.bottom - rTextLoc.top) / 2;
            long x = (rTextLoc.right - rTextLoc.left) / 2;
            XFORM xForm;
            float iAngle = 270;
            float fAngle = -static_cast<float>(iAngle) * static_cast<float>(M_PI) / 180.0f;         
xForm.eM11 = (FLOAT) cos(fAngle);
            xForm.eM12 = (FLOAT) sin(fAngle);
            xForm.eM21 = (FLOAT) -sin(fAngle);
            xForm.eM22 = (FLOAT) cos(fAngle);
            xForm.eDx  = (FLOAT) (x * (1 - cos(fAngle))) + (sin(fAngle) * y);
            xForm.eDy  = (FLOAT) (-sin(fAngle) * x) + (y * (1 - cos(fAngle)));


                xForm.eDx += (FLOAT) ((rTextLoc.bottom - rTextLoc.top) / 2) - ((rTextLoc.right - rTextLoc.left) / 2);
                xForm.eDy += (FLOAT) ((rTextLoc.bottom - rTextLoc.top) / 2) - ((rTextLoc.right - rTextLoc.left) / 2);

            SetWorldTransform(hdcScreen, &xForm); 
            SetGraphicsMode(hdcText, GM_COMPATIBLE);

            SelectObject(hdcText, hFont);
            DrawText(hdcText, m_sIdentifier.c_str(), -1, &rTextLoc, DT_CENTER | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER);
            StretchBlt(hdcScreen, 0,0,iWidth,iHeight, hdcText, 0,0,iWidth,iHeight, SRCINVERT);
            ReleaseDC(m_hWindow, hdcText);

            if(m_bFlipped)
                StretchBlt(hdcScreen, iWidth,iHeight,-iWidth,-iHeight, hdcScreen, 0,0,iWidth,iHeight, SRCCOPY);

             DeleteObject(hWorking);
             DeleteObject(hBmp);
             DeleteObject(hbmpText);

             DeleteObject(hFont);

             DeleteObject(hdcMem);
             DeleteObject(hdcText);

             EndPaint( m_hWindow, &ps );

        }
```

2. Rotation using LOGFONT. I've set the values of lfEscapement and lfOrientation. The text is moving but only on the escapement vector. The desired result is to have a rotation on a set point.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "The `SetWorldTransform` function will fail unless the graphics mode for the given device context has been set to `GM_ADVANCED` by previously calling the `SetGraphicsMode` function". You do call `SetGraphicsMode`, but not on the HDC on which you call `SetWorldTransform`. Check return values - the call is probably failing.

Comment: "Rotation using LOGFONT. I've set the values of lfEscapement lf.Orientation. The text is moving but only on the escapement vector. The desired result is to have a rotation on a set point." Could you explain what that means? Do you mean you want to specify the center of the rotation?

Comment: Response to @IgorTandetnik: I have changed that and now the HDC  value I'm trying to rotate is not being displayed on the screen.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I want to rotate the text on the screen 270 degrees anti clockwise i.e the orientation of the text. What is happening is the value is moving along the escapement vector and not rotating on it's original position. This occurs even when I do not set the value of lfEscapement.

Comment: @Dprog: "the value is moving along the escapement vector" doesn't explain much, at least to me. Perhaps you could draw a picture of what to help slow people like me understand? (and no, I'm not being sarcastic--I'm honestly lost as to either what's happening or what you want.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Sorry Jerry. My response wasn't great.

Comment: @JerryCoffin By escapement vector I mean rotation occurs on the object like a clock. Imagine the Text being display on the Hand of a clock at 12. When I rotate the text 180 degrees anticlockwise instead of 12 being upside down at its original point. It has just moved to the 6 o clock position. http://sketchtoy.com/68734328

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, you apparently want to rotate the individual characters in a string you print out, without changing the angle of the baseline of the string itself.

To do that, you want to leave the `lfEscapement` at 0, and change only the `lfOrientation` of the font. To create a font where `lfEscapement` and `lfOrientation` have different values, you need to set "advanced" graphics mode, so the sequence looks like:

```
SetGraphicsMode(yourDC, GM_ADVANCED);
HFONT font = CreateFont(20, 0, 0, 1800, FW_NORMAL, 0, 0, 0, FF_SWISS,
                        OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS, CLIP_CHARACTER_PRECIS, CLEARTYPE_QUALITY,
                        ANSI_CHARSET, L"Arial");

auto old_font = SelectObject(yourDC, font);

TextOutW(yourDC, 50, 50, L"Your Text");
```

And your result should look something like this:

[image]

Of course, if you want the text upside down (as shown in the link in your comment) you'd need to change the `lfOrientation` to 1800, to get a result like this:

[image]

As a side note, kerning can get pretty funky for some intermediate angles. For example, at 130 degrees rotation:

[image]

Pretty badly kemed, to put it mildly.

Comment: When playing with changing the orientation before I was creating the LOGFONT lf and accessing the orientation by lf.lfOrientation. 

This didn't work. However, changing the orientation in the CreateFont function worked like a charm.

Cheers Jerry.